# Prove that set with complex numbers is circumference

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Preparing for an exam, I have come up against this problem and I'm not capable to finish it. Could you give me a hand with this?

Given two complex numbers $\alpha, \beta$, and positive $\rho \neq 1$, justifies that set

$$\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \frac{|z-\alpha|}{|z-\beta|} = \rho\}$$

represents a circumference and calculate center and radius of that circumference.

Comment: Presumably $\alpha \neq \beta$?

Comment: Can be $\alpha = \beta$

Comment: If $\alpha = \beta$ then the set is empty.

Comment: There is a geometric way of looking at this problem that will give the center and radius fairly easily... Pick two points $\alpha, \beta$ on the plane and draw a line between them.

Comment: And analitically?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius?

Comment: No. How would explain solution with basic complex variable tools?

Comment: Miguel, I added a solution using basic complex algebra.

Comment: (I should add that it took me a few pages of mistakes to grind through the formula.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $C=\{w | |w| = \rho \}$ is a circle or radius $\rho$ centered at the origin.

The map $f(z) = {z-\alpha \over z-\beta}$ is a Möbius transformation (assuming $\alpha \ne \beta$) and has an inverse $g(z) = {\beta z -\alpha \over z-1}$.

Let $S= \{z | |f(z)| = \rho \}$, then $z \in S$ **iff** $f(z) \in C$ **iff** $z \in g(C)$.

A Möbius transformation maps (Riemann) circles to (Riemann) circles, so we see that $S$ is a Riemann circle.

If $z \in C$ we see that $z \neq 1$ (as $\rho \neq 1$) and so $g(z)$ is finite for all $z \in C$, hence $g(C)$ is a circle in the usual sense.

**Alternative answer**:

First, notice that a circle of radius $r$ centered at $c$ is defined by the
equation $|z-c|=r$ which (when squared) yields 
$|z|^2 - 2 \operatorname{re} c \bar{z} +|c|^2 = r^2$.

As long as $\rho \neq 1$ and $\alpha \neq \beta$, we see that the set in question can be defined by $|z-\alpha| = \rho |z-\beta|$ and squaring gives
$|z|^2 - 2 \operatorname{re} \alpha \bar{z} +|\alpha|^2 = \rho^2 (|z|^2 - 2 \operatorname{re} \beta \bar{z} +|\beta|^2)$ or
$|z|^2 - 2 \operatorname{re} {(\alpha - \rho^2 \beta) \over 1 - \rho^2} \bar{z} +{ |\alpha|^2 - \rho^2 |\beta|^2 \over 1 - \rho^2 } = 0$.

If we compare with the above equation, this suggests that the centre is
$c={\alpha - \rho^2 \beta \over 1 - \rho^2 }$ and so the equation can be written as
$|z-c|^2 = |c|^2 - { |\alpha|^2 - \rho^2 |\beta|^2 \over 1 - \rho^2 } $.

If we expand $|c|^2$ we get $|c|^2 - { |\alpha|^2 - \rho^2 |\beta|^2 \over 1 - \rho^2 } = | {\rho(\beta-\alpha) \over 1-\rho^2} |^2$, so letting
$r= | {\rho(\beta-\alpha) \over 1-\rho^2} |$ we get the desired result.

Comment: Try to explain the solution to a person that is beginning with Complex Variable hahaha

Comment: What sort of topics have you covered so far?

Comment: Until Residue Theorem, but it's a problem from first topic of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is the complexification of [a classical definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius'_definition_of_a_circle) of the circle. We can parameterise the solutions with a real $\theta$ viz.$$\frac{z-\alpha}{z-\beta}=\rho\exp i\theta\iff z=\frac{\alpha-\rho\beta\exp i\theta}{1-\rho\exp i\theta}.$$Define $\gamma:=\frac{\alpha+\rho\beta}{1+\rho},\,\delta:=\frac{\alpha-\rho\beta}{1-\rho}$ so$$z-\gamma=\frac{\alpha-\rho\beta\exp i\theta}{1-\rho\exp i\theta}-\frac{\alpha+\rho\beta}{1+\rho}=\frac{\rho(\alpha-\beta)(\exp i\theta-1)}{(1-\rho\exp i\theta)(1+\rho)}$$and$$z-\delta=\frac{\alpha-\rho\beta\exp i\theta}{1-\rho\exp i\theta}-\frac{\alpha-\rho\beta}{1-\rho}=\frac{\rho(\alpha-\beta)(\exp i\theta+1)}{(1-\rho\exp i\theta)(1-\rho)}=-i\left[\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}\cot\frac{\theta}{2}\right](z-\gamma).$$Since $\frac{z-\gamma}{z-\delta}$ is imaginary, $\angle \gamma z\delta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $z$ in the locus, so it's a circle with $\gamma,\,\delta$ the ends of a diameter. Its centre is$$\frac{\gamma+\delta}{2}=\frac{\alpha-\rho^2\beta}{1-\rho^2},$$while the diameter is$$\left|\frac{\gamma-\delta}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{\rho(\beta-\alpha)}{1-\rho^2}\right|.$$